# One-Class Support Vector Machine with categorical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, one-hot-encoding

Im trying to train a ML-model for predicting anomalous messages in the Controller Area Network (CAN) for vehicles. The idea is to have a one-class support vector machine (OCSVM) that takes frequency of messages (Hz) as one feature and message IDs as another (The IDs is in hexadecimal) and to train a OCSVM for the normal data, then predict anomalies out of other datasets with some malicious messages. The issue is that I don't know how to preprocess the ID. I have tried following approaches:

- Sort the IDs, re-mapping the ID to a numeric value i.e. 1-27 (tot. 27 IDs). Issue: The IDs should not be considered continuous since the "higher" ID should not impact the outcome of a prediction. Which led me to my second approach.
- Treat the IDs as categorical data, by some research I found one-hot encoding being an efficient way to transform the IDs.

I'm using sci-kit learn as framework. Now Im facing some issues and questions with my code:

- Firstly, I get the error when transforming the IDs with sklearn OneHotEnconder. Exporting the new dataframe to a csv lets me see that the ID is now an array but in the form of a string (see image below). And I think it causes some issues.
- Secondly, I have no idea or understanding of how the new encoded feature will be used as input to the model?
- Thirdly, should I normalize/standardize the encoded values? Does that even make any sense?
- Lastly, I get this error (see error + code below) with my current implementation:

Any help or feedback is greatly appreciated!

[image]

(Image of test .csv)

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1675, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    make_block(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 2732, in make_block
    return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 142, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 27, placement implies 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/models/OCSVM.py", line 19, in <module>
    temp_df_train = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["ID"], data = new_train_ID)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 558, in __init__
    mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 238, in init_ndarray
    return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1687, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    raise construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (13716, 27), indices imply (13716, 1)
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM
from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import where
import numpy as np

train_data = pd.read_csv("../Data/HCRL_Car-Hacking_Dataset/normal_data_set/normal_frequency_interval.csv") 
test_data = pd.read_csv("../Data/HCRL_Car-Hacking_Dataset/dos_data_set/dos_frequency_interval.csv") 

df_train = train_data[["ID", "Frequency"]]
df_test = test_data[["ID", "Frequency"]]

#------Encoding Categorically (IDs)--------
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
#Train data
new_train_ID = enc.fit_transform(train_data["ID"].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
temp_df_train = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["ID"], data = new_train_ID)
df_train = df_train.drop(["ID"], axis=1)
df_train = pd.concat([df_train, temp_df_train], axis=1)
#Test Data
new_test_ID = enc.fit_transform(test_data["ID"].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
temp_df_test = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["ID"], data = new_test_ID)
df_test = df_test.drop(["ID"], axis=1)
df_test = pd.concat([df_test, temp_df_test], axis=1)


df_train.to_csv("onehot.csv")


#Normalization
# df_train[["ID", "Frequency"]] = preprocessing.normalize(train_data[["ID", "Frequency"]])
# df_test[["ID", "Frequency"]] = preprocessing.normalize(test_data[["ID", "Frequency"]])

#Standardization
# scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(df_train)
# scaler.transform(df_train)
# scaler.transform(df_test)


# model specification
model = OneClassSVM(kernel="rbf", gamma=0.1, nu=0.1)
#model = LocalOutlierFactor(novelty=True, n_neighbors=20)

#train model
model.fit(df_train)
prediction = model.predict(df_test)

#Plotting
plt.xlabel("Message ID")
plt.ylabel("Frequency (Hz)")


outlier_index = where(prediction == -1) 
outlier_values = df_test.iloc[outlier_index]
print(test_data[["ID", "Frequency"]].iloc[outlier_index]) #I want to see what IDS are anomal
plt.scatter(df_train.ID,df_train.Frequency);
plt.scatter(outlier_values["ID"],outlier_values["Frequency"])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the dataset presented in the image and created a function that, given a dataframe with the frequency and ids, returns a dataframe with the frequency and columns of the generated one-hot-vector. That way you can pass the dataframe that function returns to OCSVM to train. On the issue of normalization, I think it's good to compare normalized vs. non-normalized so you can get an idea of how OCSVM is performing on each data type.

Tip: merge the training and test data into a single dataframe to use the function I gave you, then separate the returned dataframe into two dataframes again (training and test).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Frequency', 'ID'])
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 15, 'ID' : '1'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 1, 'ID' : '2'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 1, 'ID' : '3'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 15, 'ID' : '4'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 15, 'ID' : '5'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 15, 'ID' : '6'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 15, 'ID' : '7'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 15, 'ID' : '8'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 8, 'ID' : '9'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 15, 'ID' : '10'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 15, 'ID' : '11'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 15, 'ID' : '12'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 15, 'ID' : '13'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 15, 'ID' : '14'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Frequency' : 15, 'ID' : '15'}, ignore_index=True)

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np

def df_onehot(df, num_ids):
  features_cat = ['ID']

  pipeline_cat = Pipeline(steps=[('onehot', OneHotEncoder())])

  transf = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('transformacao categorica', pipeline_cat, features_cat)])

  dt = transf.fit_transform(df)

  names = ['Frequency']
  for id in range(1,num_ids+1):
    tring = 'Id'
    names.append(tring)

  data_ok = np.concatenate([[df['Frequency'].to_list()], dt.toarray().T])

  df_ok = pd.DataFrame(data = data_ok.T, columns=names)
  df_ok

  return df_ok

df_train = df_onehot(df, 15)
```